# set html checkbox value

Tags: xslt

I am trying to design a form using xsl which parses a simple xml file; like this:

```
<tests>
    <agent ID="1" Name="Name 1"  />
    <agent ID="2" Name="Name 2"  />
    <agent ID="3" Name="Name 3"  />
</tests>
```

and xsl file:

```
<form action="." method="post"  >
        <xsl:for-each select="tests">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="agent">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="" /> </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </form>
```

I want the value of checkbox to be the ID value.(`<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>`). but I cannot use this tag inside checkbox tag. 
What should I do?

Comment: Maryam, I would recommend that you read and use the answer by @TimC. The AVT notation greatly simplifies the code and makes it shorter and less vulnerable to errors -- also much more understandable. I don't think you have accepted the best answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<xsl:attribute>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) will allow you to add arbitrary attributes to tags.

> The `xsl:attribute` element can be used to add attributes to result elements whether created by literal result elements in the stylesheet or by instructions such as `xsl:element`.

```
<picture>
  <xsl:attribute name="source">foo</xsl:attribute>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 4):

As well as the `<xsl:attribute>` element mentioned elsewhere, it is also worth learing about [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) as these can often help simplify your XSLT code. These allow you to put an expression directly in an attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="{@Value}" />
```

The curly braces { } indicate this is an "AVT" and contain an expression to be evaluated.

You can even use them in the `<xsl:attribute>` if you wanted dynamic attribute names based on some value in the XML.

```
<xsl:attribute name="{$attrname}">
```